# Can't able to copy value? Is logic error? or print error?

Tags: c

Hi i have below simple program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef unsigned long long  uint64;

void getvalue(uint64 *getValue)
{
    unsigned char arr[8] = {0xAB, 0xCD, 0x12, 0x34, 0xFF, 0xED, 0xCA, 0x01};
    memcpy(getValue, arr, sizeof(uint64));
}

void main()
{
    uint64 getValue;
    getvalue(&getValue);    
    printf("value :0x%08x and sizeof(uint64) = %d", getValue, sizeof(uint64));
}
```

This program to copy content in 8 byte variable but when i ran it i see below output which shows only 4 bytes copied.

```
value :0x3412cdab and sizeof(uint64) = 8
```

So can anyone point out me what is the issue?

Comment: [This `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might be helpful. The `"%x"` format is for printing `unsigned int` values. Technically you're using the wrong format for the size as well. Depending on the compiler, you should have gotten warnings about it.

Comment: Use `0x%08llx` instead of `0x%08x`. Also Use `%zu` for `size_t`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes that helps.Thanks

Comment: `%llx` for `unsigned long long` and `%zu` for `size_t` (the type of `sizeof)`.

Comment: Avoid defining custom types for primitives: use `uint64_t` from `stdint.h`  with format specifier `PRIx64` when possible.

Answer (score 3):

The copy is ok, You have to printf with long long unsigned

```
printf("0x%llx", (unsigned long long) getValue);
```

Comment: Nevermind, it was my bad. Removed my comment. No cast needed.